# make scrapy requests from subfunction

Tags: python, scrapy, generator

If I make scrapy requests from a subfunction I get this error:

```
ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'generator'
```

Example code:

```
def parse(self):
    yield self.subfunc(link)

def subfunc(self):
    yield scrapy.Request(link)
```

I assume it has to do with the way generators work but I am not really familiar with them. Any quick fix? I would like to use the subfunction to organise the code a little bit.
I am writing to a `csv` myself so I do not need to yield items or dicts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code yields the generator, you want to yield requests from that generator instead.
Probably the best way to do that is using `yield from`:

```
def parse(self):
    yield from self.subfunc(link)
```

**Edit:**

Since `yield from` syntax is new in python 3.3, on older versions you'll have to loop over the values yielded by the generator:

```
def parse(self):
    for request in self.subfunc(link):
        yield request
```

Comment: thank you stranac. But my compilator says this syntax is not suported < 3.3. Use explicit iteration over subgenerator.
(I am using 2.7 because I need some libs)

Comment: thanks again. it's been a huge help, my python is still really basic

Comment: Spent hours on stack to find that answer !
Was all about that `from`...